# Select2 js Plugin Not able to select any option

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, html, jquery-select2

I am using [Select2.js](https://select2.github.io/)(latest version) to implement tokenized tagging in my application. It is working fine except, **I am not able to select any item from the suggestions**.

I saw few answers in which it was mentioned that we need to include "id" in our configuration. it doesn't seems to be working for me.

My code is :

```
$("#interest").select2({ ajax: {
            url: "get-interests",
            dataType: 'json',
            delay: 250,
            data: function (params) {
              return {
                q: params.term, // search term
                page: params.page
              };
            },
            processResults: function (data, page) {
              // parse the results into the format expected by Select2.
              // since we are using custom formatting functions we do not need to
              // alter the remote JSON data
              return {
                results: data
              };
            },
            cache: true
          },
          escapeMarkup: function (markup) { return markup; }, // let our custom formatter work
          placeholder:{
              id: "-1",
              text: "Add your interest.."
          } ,
          tags: true,
          tokenSeparators: [',', ' '],
          id: function(data) { 
              alert(JSON.stringify(data));
              return data.interestId; 
          },
          templateResult: function(post) {
              // return html markup for individual result item
              var markup ="";
              if(String(post.description) !== 'undefined') {
                 markup = '<p><b>' + post.text + '</b>  : ' + post.description + '</p>';
              } else {
                 markup = '<p><b>' + post.text + '</b></p>';
              }
              return markup;
           },
           formatSelection: function(post) {
              // This shows up in the select box
              return post.text;
           }
```

What I am doing wrong in above configuration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Contrary to the comment you placed in your code, with Select2 4.0 you do need to add code to the `processResults` function to convert the returned JSON data to objects with an `id` property. Normally, the objects should also have a `text` property, but they don't have to if you supply the `templateResult` and `templateSelection` functions.

> I saw few answers in which it was mentioned that we need to include
>   "id" in our configuration. it doesn't seems to be working for me.

Those answers were correct for previous versions of Select2, but with with Select2 v4.0, the `id` function is no longer supported. See the "The id and text properties are strictly enforced" section on the the ["4.0 Anouncement"](https://select2.github.io/announcements-4.0.html) page:

You can also remove the `formatSelection` function. With Select2 4.0 it should now be named `templateSelection`. That means it is not getting called for you, but you probably didn't notice that because your `formatSelection` function is just doing what is done by default anyway.

---

The `processResults` function should return an object with a `results` property, which is set to an array of objects. Those objects all need to have an `id` property (but they can have other properties too).

You don't show what your returned `data` looks like, but judging from your `id` and `templateResult` functions, it appears to be an array of objects with the following properties: `interestId`, `text` and `description`. In that case your `processResults` function could look something like this:

```
// This builds a new array of new objects.
processResults: function(data, page) {
    return {
        results: $.map(data, function(post) {
            return {
                id: post.interestId,
                text: post.text,
                description: post.description
            };
        })
    };
},
```

Or this:

```
// This just adds an `id` property to the objects in the existing array.
processResults: function(data, page) {
    $.each(data, function(i, post) {
        post.id = post.interestId;
    });
    return { results: data };
},
```

Comment: in `processResult`, data is a JSON object so I need to get id and text  from that and create a new object. am i right?..It will be really helpful if you can show me some working example or write a small fiddle for me. Thanks

Comment: @user3035305 - I have added to my answer to show what the `processResults` function could look like.